# Inversion with l'impératif

Tags: grammaire, impératif, inversion

Coucou!

I’m studying l’impératif and I’m a bit confused with regards to inversion. When we first learn how to ask a question we see that to formally ask you invert the subject and the verb (Parlez-vous Français ?) But I see that l’impératif also uses inversion for certain phrases. How do I know which phrases use inversion and which ones don’t? Also why is the rule inconsistent? Why is it that in some cases inversion indicates an order (“Dépêche-toi”) and some indicate a question (“Parles-toi Français”)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you ask a question using the inversion the verb has a **subject**, "inversion" means here inverting the verb with its subject.

- *Parles-**tu*** français ? The subject is *tu*.

When you give an order (imperative) the verb does **not have a subject** (and there is no inversion whatsoever).

- *Parle français* ! There is no subject, just the verb (and an object here).

That was a basic case. Now I'm going to use the reflexive verb *se laver* and it is a little more complicated.

**Question with inversion**: *Te laves-**tu** les mains* ? The subject **tu** is after the verb, like in the previous example. In front of the verb we have the **reflexive pronoun**.

**Imperative**: *Lave-toi les mains*. There is still no subject, neither before nor after the verb. *Toi* is not the subject, it is the **reflexive pronoun**.

Your sentence  <strike>*Parles-toi Français*</strike> is wrong, it just can't exist.

In order not to be confused I suggest you learn how to conjugate a reflexive verb. In the following sentences the reflexive pronoun is **bolded**. The verb is ***se** laver*.

**Affirmative** :
*Je **me** lave

Tu **te** laves

Elle/il **se** lave

Nous **nous** lavons

Vous **vous** lavez

Elles/ils **se** lavent*

**Question** with inversion :

***Me** lavé-je ?<sup>1</sup>

**Te** laves-tu ?

**Se** lave-t-elle/il ?

**Nous** lavons-nous ?

**Vous** lavez-vous ?

**Se** lavent-ils ?*

**Imperative**:
*Lave-**toi*** !
*Lavons-**nous*** !
*Lavez-**vous*** !

Notice that in the imperative the reflexive pronoun *te* becomes *toi* (*toi* is called an emphatic pronoun but it is not important you remember what it's called at that stage, you'll have other occasions to use it and lean more about it). What I'd suggest you do at that stage is to make sure you know the subject personal pronouns, you can conjugate a reflexive verb and know how to use the reflexive pronouns and don't confuse the lists since some pronouns are common to both lists, but not all.

For further study :
Reflexive verbs on [Collins grammar](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/french-easy-learning/reflexive-verbs), on [Learn to French](https://learntofrench.com/reflexive-verbs-in-french-present/)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> An accent is added on the "e" (*lavé*) to facilitate the pronunciation. But with *je* the *est-ce que* question (*est-ce que je me lave ?*) is more usual.</sup>

Comment: (Of course, you could say "Parle-toi !" as a bizarre command, and even "Parle-toi en français !")

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! This was really helpful.

Comment: @LukeSawczak Parle-toi ! Yes, a command. I don't quite get it. In their question the OP says *Parles-toi Français* with an ***s*** and referring to a question.

Comment: @None Indeed, I'm just filling in the picture :)

Comment: Definetely I agree with you and upvoted your answer. Yet there's the intonation which makes a difference too.

Comment: Why not make a general statement about reflexive verbs? se dépêcher is not an "unreflexive verb": parler. One is a command with a reflexive verb and the other is a regular question form.....